# How to display a HTML code in Chrome Extension Popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I want to display a Amazon Affiliate Widget Code in the popup section of a chrome extension.

The manifest.json looks like this(Copied as it is from Google Repository):

```css
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

The backgroung.js is blank.
The Popup.html looks like this:

```css
<html>
    <head>
 <title>
 Amazon
 </title>
 </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Amazon Search</h1>
 <script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">
amzn_assoc_ad_type = "responsive_search_widget";
amzn_assoc_tracking_id = "smart0e-21";
amzn_assoc_marketplace = "amazon";
amzn_assoc_region = "IN";
amzn_assoc_placement = "";
amzn_assoc_search_type = "search_widget";
amzn_assoc_width = "auto";
amzn_assoc_height = "auto";
amzn_assoc_default_search_category = "";
amzn_assoc_default_search_key = "";
amzn_assoc_theme = "light";
amzn_assoc_bg_color = "FFFFFF";
</script>
<script src="//z-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&Operation=GetScript&ID=OneJS&WS=1&MarketPlace=IN"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

I am new to this extension development and also new to HTML.
Please help me, I want to run the search widget in the popup.
This is what happens when I click on the Extension.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3gK2.png
Thanks.

Comment: I'm new to html and nothing happens when I insert it in popup.HTML & even I don't know where should the code go!

Comment: follow a sample for popup. so not link to external js.

Answer (score 0):

You can't link to external links in the popup.html file. Instead, you should add a separate javascript file to your extension's background and call the widget's script from there.

Your manifest will look something like this (don't forget to add Content-Security-Policy rules):

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Getting started example",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : [ "background.js" ],
  },
  "content_security_policy" : "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' http://z-in.amazon-adsystem.com; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/",
    "http://z-in.amazon-adsystem.com/"
  ]
}
```

Your background.js file can call the script in an iframe:

```
 (function() {
    var widget = document.createElement('iframe');
    widget.src = "//z-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?ServiceVersion=20070822&Operation=GetScript&ID=OneJS&WS=1&MarketPlace=IN";
    widget.id = 'widget';
    document.body.appendChild(widget);

    //assign your widget variables
  })();
```

And your popup.html can just have a script link to your background file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../background.js"></script>
```

I haven't tested this, but it's the general gist of how to run external scripts in your extension.